# How to take bit number 3 from 8 bits

Tags: python, bitmask

I have this in hex: `08`
Which is this in binary: `0000 1000` (bit positions: 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)

Now I would like to make a bitmask in python, so I have bit position 3.
Here in example `1` or better (the one in ""): `0000 "1"000`

What shall I do to have only this bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shift right by the bit index to have that bit in the 0th position, then AND with 1 to isolate it.

```py
val = 0b01001000  # note the extra `1` to prove this works
pos = 3
bit = (val >> pos) & 1
print(bit)
```

outputs `1`

Answer (score 4):

you could just do this:

```
def get_bit(n, pos):
    return (n >> pos) & 1

res = get_bit(n=8, pos=3) 
# 1
```

shift the number `n` left by `pos` bits (`>> pos`) and then mask away the rest (`& 1`).

the doc on [Bitwise Operations on Integer Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) may help.